# Create a page for plugin view page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in WordPress.I want to create a plugin.This plugin have admin panel for some settings and view page for the end users.Now for end user my page link is like

```
www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/my_page.php
```

This url looks ugly.Is there any way that i can found the page id of my plugin view page when plugin will be activated and gives url link like this?

```
http://mysite.com/?page_id=$my_page_id
```

or is there any way when plugin will activated then i use single_template to show my view pages??
i want to show plugin view pages like template pages to end user. Any kind of help (provide useful resources,tricks,steps to do it) would be useful for me.

**Another issues**
I want create a shortcode for this plugin view page. I have googling and see some examples. I have done this so far in my plugin file:

```
function xx_footer_menu_link(){
     return "ADD TO FOOTER";
}

add_shortcode('my_plugin_xx',"xx_footer_menu_link" );
```

And I have added it to template footer like this:

```
 <?php echo  do_shortcode([my_plugin_xx]);  ?>
```

I also tried this with out PHP tag. It shows `Array` in footer as output. No link is appear in the footer. What am I missing here?

Comment: Too many questions, you should focus on one issue per question. I'm voting to close as *Not A Real Question*. I see you don't have a [wordpress.se] account :) Research within the tag [\[plugin-development\]](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development), you'll find lots of resources and examples. Final tips: read the page [ask] and use the WYSIWYG tools to format your Question properly. . . . `<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_plugin_xx]'); ?>`

Comment: Hi brasofilo,Thanks for response.I have asked 2 questions.First: plugin view page integration to theme with a page url.Second: shortcode problem.

Comment: Hi brasofilo,shortcode is not working.I have tried us you said.it gives [my_plugin_xx] again.i also tried  <?php echo do_shortcode([my_plugin_xx]); ?> it shows Array.

Comment: I just return hello like this: return "hello"; but it gives output: Array

Comment: Hi brasofilo, i have updated my question.Would you please take a look??

Comment: You're still asking 2 questions. One off-topic, other *too-localized*. I've tested `echo do_shortcode('[your-shortcode-function]');` and it works ok.

Comment: Hi,I do not get what i am missing here.It always shows Array in the output.About first one: is it possible or not?If its not possible then for end user all plugin page link(www.site.com/plugin/plugin_name/page_name.php) never looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcode is now working fine.a little bit of change in calling shortcode like that 
`<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_plugin_xx]Booking[/my_plugin_xx]');  ?>`
Has done the issues.About first problem i have move my view page for front end users from the plugin directory to template directory as a template. Now After activate plugin admin need to create a blank page with my view page template.In my view page i put all my code and it works like a template page.In admin panel admin can add this tamplate to anywhere in the menu.